# Background url for a div

Tags: html, css

With these styles and this html the image specified in the background url isn't shown.  What could be the problem?  The urls are right.

```
<style>
    .copy_tool {
    width: 17px;
    height: 15px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    background: url("/images/copy_tool.png") no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    }

    .print_tool {
    width: 17px;
    height: 15px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    background: url("/images/print_tool.png") no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    }

</style>

<div class="toolbox">
    <div id="copy_readfe" class="copy_tool" title="Copy"></div>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <div id="print_readfe" class="print_tool" title="Print" onclick="print_element('div_readfe');"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: my guess is your URLs are not right.

Comment: Try to put something into your divs - an `&nbsp;` will suffice. Like `<div id="copy_readfe" class="copy_tool" title="Copy">&nbsp;</div>`

Comment: this is offtopic, but if you're creating a "toolbox" as it appears you are, you should probably be using a `<ul>` and anchor tags. Just sayin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The css and html is correct as [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeymagic/aWMjS/) proves. Your paths are most likely broken or your images are not showing because of some kind of internal issue.

However your markup could be done better like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeymagic/aWMjS/1/) ( removing redundant css ) or better yet in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeymagic/aWMjS/2/) ( conversion to a ul li setup).

**Reference**

- [background-image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Comment: The browser seems to look for the images in the root directory of the webserver.  It doesn't look in the directory where the page is.

Comment: I think that is an issue with your server/hosting configuration. You could always use absolute paths if you don't figure it out but yeah; this most likely cannot be fixed with css or html

Comment: If I specify the url to be "./images/filename.png" this works.  Adding the dot makes the browser start from the current directory.

Comment: ahh true, well there you go :)